# Validation - file name required if file upload has file

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, eloquent

im having a form controller for an inventory, where people can add items and add bills, manuals etc too while creating the items. My problem is, that i want to get a file name too (e.g. Bill for the uploaded file) but i only want to require it, if they really have a file chosen in the form.

my code right now looks like this:

i tried everything out like required_unless, required_if but nothing works.  Maybe i do sth wrong or my idea just doesnt work with this validation rules?

The validation in the Controller:

```
public function save(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'file' => 'nullable|file',
            'files_label' => 'required_unless:file,empty|string',
        ]);
```

The error message in my html is: 
files_label has to be a string (so i guess its still required)...

my blade looks like this

```
<input class="form--textinput" name="files_label" id="files_label" value="{{old('files_label')}}">
<input type="file" class="custom-file" name="file" id="file" value="{{old('file')}}">
```

How can i make it work that, it just requires the file_label if i chose a file to upload?

**UPDATE 1:** tried it out with type="text" too. still getting the error: "The files label must be a string."

**UPDATE 2:** So I deleted the type requirement "string" and now it looks, like it works. he doesnt want the files_label field to be a string. required_unless works now too as it looks like. Can someone tell my why it is like that? Why he wants a string, if the field is not required at all?

code looks like this now:

```
'file' => 'nullable|file',
'files_label' => 'required_unless:file,',
```

Comment: Why files_label input field has no type?

Comment: The first input is missing a type, should be `type="text"` (though thats default if not provided). Try with your validation as `'files_label' => 'required_if:file|string',` -- also, using `old()` on a `type="file"` isn't going to work.

Comment: oh yeah forgot that one... set the type now.. required_if requires 2 parameters... tried it out too...

Comment: @EdizDeniz when you add string validation it expects a string unless you give it to it. So if you keep the files_label input empty it will give error

Comment: but if i make sth: nullable|string, or sometimes|string it doesnt give out this kind of error. weheres the difference to required_unless? required_unless has also a not required case which means nullable or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `required_with` in this case . like this

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
                'file' => 'nullable|file',
                'files_label' => 'required_with:file,empty|string',
            ]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-required-with

Comment: Tried that one too: the error: "The files label must be a string." still comes up, i dont know why... if i remove the " |string " part from the validation required_unless works fine... but i dont get why...

Comment: @EdizDeniz that's because files_label is missing type